# ORA-12532: TNS:invalid argument

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

My applicatino is giving **ORA-12532: TNS:invalid argument** exception. My app is in C# and I am using ODP.Net to connect to oracle database.

I googled for this error but couldnt find much information. I found [this](http://tns-12532.ora-code.com/) page where it says this error occures when internal method receives invalid parameters. I am not sure how to regenerate this exception as this error has occured on client's enviornment and my app works fine on my enviornment.

Has anyone encountered this error? How to avoid this error?

Comment: What code is causing this error?

Comment: @Shadow, I checked stacktrace, Call to open() connection is causing this error

Comment: Cheers, please comment on Codo answer with that actually solved the problem for the sake of others with same problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely causes:

- Invalid TNS names configuration (check the tnsnames.ora files)
- Prolematic characters in the password (in particular the @ sign can cause problems)
- Too strict firewall rules (unable to connect to port 1521)

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=545068) it's possible your TNS entry is misconfigured, or that one of the system accounts has a special character in the password (like `@`).